# I wonder what is different between separator and terminator in printing?

Tags: swift, separator, terminator

I am wondering about this printing thing. You could notice this code concept different between this code concept.

```
print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, separator: "...")
//1...2...3...4...5
```

and

```
for n in 1...5 {
    print(n, separator: " ", terminator: "...")
}
// 1...2...3...4...5...
```

I thought  **separator supposed be space for add text each of the items but terminators for default the newlines as known \n** which you could see newlines sign if you were using the swift playground as well. If you put that three periods on the separator could not display that '...' on loops but printing can. I get a bit confuse about this code. so Let me know about this code. Might I was wrong at those things. I was learning about Swift.

Comment: The difference becomes obvious when you print multiple values with one `print` statement. Example: `print(1,2,3, separator: " ", terminator: "...")`.

Comment: This means terminator will use for many items in the printing statements, right?

Comment: You are not printing any separator. The separator it is used to connect the variadic parameters but you are passing only one and printing it multiple times at the same line because you are using "..." instead of the default terminator which is a newLine character.

Answer (score 0):

As documented for the `print(_:separator:terminator:)` method:

**separator**: A string to print between each item.

**terminator**: The string to print after all items have been printed.

This is per call to `print`. So the `separator` is only useful when you provide more than one value to `print`.

```
print(arg1, arg2, ..., argN, separator: someSeparator, terminator: someTerminator)
```

This results in:

> arg1 someSeparator arg2 someSeparator ... someSeparator argN someTerminator

(but without the spaces which I added for clarity).

When you only print one value, such as in the code in your question, the `separator` isn't used at all so you are only seeing the terminator at the end of each value printed.

Code such as:

```
print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, separator: " ", terminator: "...")
```

will give the results you seem to be looking for:

> 1 2 3 4 5...

Answer (score 0):

`separator` is the text to print between the vales given to print.
 `terminator` is the text to print after all values were printed. so:

```
print(val1, val2, val3, ..., separator: "<SEP>", terminator: "<TERM>")
```

will print

```
val1<SEP>val2<SEP>val3<SEP>...<TERM>
```

if only one value is given to `print`, then it will **NOT** print the separator, because it has nothing to separate! (you don't separate one value from itself). but it will print the terminator given (or the default terminator, if one is not supplied).

therefor,

```
print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, separator: "...")
//1...2...3...4...5
```

will print the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 separated by "..." and terminated by the default terminator,
and

```
for n in 1...5 {
    print(n, separator: " ", terminator: "...")
}
// 1...2...3...4...5...
```

will print every number from 1 to 5, with the text `...` after every number, and 
will not print the separator, because the print is given only one value to print.